# Vim: copy text across buffers in one command

Tags: vim

If I want to copy lines 17-19 to line 33, I can do this in one command like this:

```
:17,19t33
```

Is there an equivalent way of doing this if the destination is another open Vim buffer? For example, if I wanted to copy lines 17,19 of the current buffer into buffer #2, is there a way to do this without yanking the text, switching buffers and pasting?

Note that I typically have the source and destination files open in a split.

Comment: The common "vim way" would be to build up the text via appending to a named register, e.g. `"Ayy`. Eventually you will want to switch to that buffer and then you paste the contents. Are there reasons against such an approach?

Comment: @PeterRincker Semantically, my brain conceives of this as a single step (copy text from this buffer to that one), so I'd like to be able to execute it in a single step instead of three steps (copy, switch buffers, paste). I didn't mention this in the original question, but usually I want to do this when both files are open in a split.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does chaining counts as a one-liner? E.g.:

```
:17,19y | b# | 33put | b#
```

Not sophisticated, but should do it. I used `b#` for convenience.

Kudos to Peter for pointing out a mistake I made -- I moved that initial buffer switch to the end.

Comment: Is this "pulling" text not "sending" text. I think you are looking for something like this: `17,19y | b2 | 33pu | b#`. May also want to set `'hidden'` or use `:hide`

Comment: @guessimtoolate could you elaborate on your answer and explain what the given paramters do? E.g. `b#` and `33put`, i've never seen them before.

Comment: `b#` changes current buffer to the one last used, `33put` pastes contents of " register on line 33. Pipe symbols `|` are used to chain commands sequentially.